# codeigniter session object expired availability

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-state

This might be a silly question.

Once a user has been logged in, if session expires I want to redirect him to a "lockscreen" instead to a "login" page.

I want to send to the lockscreen some session data (like img-src and loginname)

So, here's the question. Does session object is automatically destroyed when expires or is it still available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Session expires, session variables also becomes undefined. So always check your session like below

```
    if (isset ($_SESSION['username']))
    {
     // Its active
    }
   else
   {
     // Session expired
   }
```

Comment: Thanks AjayR for so short reply. Any suggestions for what I need to do? Maybe thru global vars?

Comment: If you want store data after login, better to store in session variables. Even cookies in scripting also can be used to store data. Global variables not recommended.